# ImportError: No module named 'basic' in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

First of all, I am a Django rookie, so pls get that.

I am trying to set up local enviroment, so I can run a web page locally on a VM.

But I am getting ImportError: No module named 'basic' in Python error, no matter if I'm trying to run as su or not.

Django version is 2.0.2
Python is 3.4.3

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpOau.png)

Comment: What are you "trying to run" ?

Comment: that would be `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: pls get that questions need a bit more detail in order for people to help out.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the actual error message. The traceback shows that the error is coming from your settings, so show the relevant code and the layout of your settings directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just here to give my two cents. There are huge advantages of using `Vagrant`. But since you just mentioned that you are a rookie. Can I interest you in virtual environment instead of virtual machine? It should get the work done as long as you are not doing something OS specific. Here's how it works:

```
$ mkdir project_name
$ cd project_name
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ django-admin startproject project_name
```

I also saw from your screenshot that you are logged in as `root`. May I please suggest you to not do that as it is bad practice?

And I think your import has a problem as @Alasdair suggested. Try putting a dot `.` in front of `basic`, which suggests that you are targeting the `basic` directory which resides in `.`, the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit relative imports do not work in Python 3. If `basic` is in your settings directory, then the import should be:

```
from .basic import *
```